# Magento language switch shows twice

Tags: magento, language-switching

I am building a webshop with Magento. I downloaded a free theme called HelloWired. I use English and Dutch in my webshop. There is a language switcher which lets the customer switch between those languages.

My problem is that this switch shows up twice. I checked the layout file `page.xml` and I noticed that it gets mentioned there twice. But if I remove one of them, it either does nothing, or removes both..

Who can help me remove one of the language switches?

This is code from the `page.xml` file:

```
    <block type="page/html" name="root" output="toHtml" template="page/3columns.phtml">

        <block type="page/html_head" name="head" as="head">
            <action method="addJs"><script>lib/ccard.js</script></action>
            <action method="addJs"><script>prototype/prototype.js</script></action>
            <action method="addJs" ifconfig="dev/js/deprecation"><script>prototype/deprecation.js</script></action>
            <action method="addJs"><script>prototype/validation.js</script></action>
            <action method="addJs"><script>scriptaculous/builder.js</script></action>
            <action method="addJs"><script>scriptaculous/effects.js</script></action>
            <action method="addJs"><script>scriptaculous/dragdrop.js</script></action>
            <action method="addJs"><script>scriptaculous/controls.js</script></action>
            <action method="addJs"><script>scriptaculous/slider.js</script></action>
            <action method="addJs"><script>varien/js.js</script></action>
            <action method="addJs"><script>varien/form.js</script></action>
            <action method="addJs"><script>varien/menu.js</script></action>
            <action method="addJs"><script>mage/translate.js</script></action>
            <action method="addJs"><script>mage/cookies.js</script></action>

            <action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><name>js/jquery-1.7.1.min.js</name></action>                
            <action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><name>js/imgpreview.js</name></action>
            <action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><name>js/hello.jquery.js</name></action>
            <action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><name>js/less.min.js</name></action>   
            <action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><name>js/respond.min.js</name><params/><if>IE</if></action>
            <action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><name>js/cufon-yui.js</name></action>
            <action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><name>js/jquery.cycle.all.js</name></action>
            <action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><name>js/custom.js</name></action>

            <action method="addCss"><stylesheet>css/widgets.css</stylesheet></action>
            <action method="addCss"><stylesheet>css/styles.css</stylesheet></action>
            <action method="addCss"><stylesheet>css/responsive.css</stylesheet></action>
            <action method="addCss"><stylesheet>css/custom.css</stylesheet></action>
            <action method="addItem"><type>skin_css</type><name>css/styles-ie.css</name><params/><if>lt IE 8</if></action>
            <action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><name>js/pngfix.js</name><params/><if>lt IE 7</if></action>
            <action method="addItem"><type>js</type><name>lib/ds-sleight.js</name><params/><if>lt IE 7</if></action>

            <action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><name>js/ie6.js</name><params/><if>lt IE 7</if></action>

            <action method="addCss"><stylesheet>css/print.css</stylesheet><params>media="print"</params></action>
        </block>

        <block type="core/text_list" name="after_body_start" as="after_body_start"/>

        <block type="page/html_notices" name="global_notices" as="global_notices" template="page/html/notices.phtml" />

        <block type="page/html_header" name="header" as="header">
            <block type="core/text_list" name="top.menu" as="topMenu"/>
            <block type="page/switch" name="store_language" as="store_language" template="page/switch/languages.phtml"/>
            <block type="page/template_links" name="top.links" as="topLinks"/>
            <block type="page/html_wrapper" name="top.bar" as="topBar" translate="label">
                <action method="setElementClass"><value>top-bar</value></action>
                <block type="page/html_breadcrumbs" name="breadcrumbs" as="breadcrumbs"/>
            </block>
            <block type="catalog/navigation" name="mobile-nav" as="mobile-nav" template="catalog/navigation/mobile-nav.phtml" />
            <block type="page/html_wrapper" name="top.container" as="topContainer" translate="label">
                <label>Page Header</label>
                <action method="setElementClass"><value>top-container</value></action>
            </block>
            <block type="page/switch" name="store_language" as="store_language" template="page/switch/languages.phtml"/>
        </block>

        <block type="core/text_list" name="left" as="left" translate="label">
            <label>Left Column</label>
        </block>

        <block type="core/messages" name="global_messages" as="global_messages"/>
        <block type="core/messages" name="messages" as="messages"/>

        <block type="core/text_list" name="content" as="content" translate="label">

            <label>Main Content Area</label>


        </block>

        <block type="core/text_list" name="right" as="right" translate="label">
            <label>Right Column</label>
        </block>

        <block type="page/html_footer" name="footer" as="footer" template="page/html/footer.phtml">
            <block type="page/html_wrapper" name="bottom.container" as="bottomContainer" translate="label">
                <label>Page Footer</label>
                <action method="setElementClass"><value>bottom-container</value></action>
            </block>
            <block type="page/template_links" name="footer_links" as="footer_links" template="page/template/links.phtml"/>
            <block type="page/switch" name="store_switcher" as="store_switcher" template="page/switch/stores.phtml"/>
        </block>

        <block type="core/text_list" name="before_body_end" as="before_body_end"/>
    </block>

    <block type="core/profiler" output="toHtml" name="core_profiler"/>
</default>

<print translate="label" module="page">
    <label>All Pages (Print Version)</label>
    <!-- Mage_Page -->
    <block type="page/html" name="root" output="toHtml" template="page/print.phtml">

        <block type="page/html_head" name="head" as="head">
            <action method="addJs"><script>lib/ccard.js</script></action>
            <action method="addJs"><script>prototype/prototype.js</script></action>
            <action method="addJs"><script>mage/translate.js</script></action>
            <action method="addJs"><script>prototype/validation.js</script></action>
            <action method="addJs"><script>varien/js.js</script></action>

            <action method="addCss"><stylesheet>css/widgets.css</stylesheet></action>
            <action method="addCss"><stylesheet>css/styles.css</stylesheet></action>
            <action method="addItem"><type>skin_css</type><name>css/styles-ie.css</name><params/><if>lt IE 8</if></action>
            <action method="addCss"><stylesheet>css/print.css</stylesheet><params>media="print"</params></action>

            <action method="addItem"><type>js</type><name>lib/ds-sleight.js</name><params/><if>lt IE 7</if></action>
            <action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><name>js/ie6.js</name><params/><if>lt IE 7</if></action>

        </block>

        <block type="core/text_list" name="content" as="content" translate="label">
            <label>Main Content Area</label>
        </block>

    </block>
</print>
```

Comment: hmm actually the one under `page/html_wrapper` block seems extra. After removing it try to refresh cache and if possible perform a reindex to make sure they are not interrupting your changes.

Comment: I tried that, but then they would either both disappear,  or nothing would change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to locate the .phtml file of your theme which builds the page. For example if the lang switcher is at the header, you need to find the header.phtml. Inside this file is probably this code `$this->getChildHtml('store_language')` or some other code related with store language, twice.